# Why can't I convert a std::string to double using atof?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert `std::string` to `float/double`.
I tried:

```
std::string num = "0.6";
double temp = (double)atof(num.c_str());
```

But it always returns zero. Any other ways?

Comment: Resist the urge to overengineer something figured out already a decade ago.

Comment: are you sure you output it correctly? It shouldn't yield zero

Comment: additionally, you do not need to cast atof, it already returns a double.

Comment: I'm sure. Debugger shows me 0. And result is 0. Platform: Linux.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right locale installed? try "0,6" or setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

Comment: Don't trust the debugger ... write temp to the outputqDebug() << temp;

Comment: Hmmm. Try playing around with the number. Does 1.0 work? 1.5?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
std::string num = "0.6";
double temp = ::atof(num.c_str());
```

Does it for me, it is a valid C++ syntax to convert a string to a double.

You can do it with the stringstream or boost::lexical_cast but those come with a performance penalty.

---

Ahaha you have a Qt project ...

```
QString winOpacity("0.6");
double temp = winOpacity.toDouble();
```

Extra note:
If the input data is a `const char*`, `QByteArray::toDouble` will be faster.

Comment: I don't see any reason why boost::lexical_cast would have a performance penalty (but a stringstream is certainly slower).

Comment: boost::lexical_cast is streaming.

Comment: You can't generally say they come with a performance penalty, i think. Think about what happens when just before it you have a cin >> num;. The user would have to type very quickly (rly jon skeet like) to ever note the milliseconds lexical_cast is slower :) That said, i believe there are tasks where lexical_cast just sucks too much performance :)

Comment: ... there is always a performance penalty, this penalty can be significant or not for the performance of the application.  If the user can type very very very quickly it will be significant ;)

Comment: Thanks... I needn't in Boost. And i've forgot about Qt :D.

Comment: For this solution, what does the :: in front of atof() do? What does it need to be there?

Comment: @ShaChris Because I want to make sure I use the atof function from the global namespace.

Comment: Do you have an alternative for `string` to `float` that doesn't use `stof` (which only comes with new C++11)

Comment: strtod() is better if you're worried about bad values. Also, both of these won't throw exceptions, which is great.

Comment: depends on the current locale

Comment: Why is the scope resolution operator used here? `::atof(num.c_str());`

Answer (score 131):

The Standard Library (C++11) offers the desired functionality with [`std::stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) :

```
std::string  s  = "0.6"
std::wstring ws = "0.7"
double d  = std::stod(s);
double dw = std::stod(ws);
```

Generally for most other basic types, see [`<string>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/). There are some new features for C strings, too. See [`<stdlib.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/)

Comment: I like this solution, but it appears that it is only from C++11. So not available on my SDK.

Comment: It's ___great___ to know that the C++ standards committee added this. `ostringstream` in itself was simply too long to type out, let alone use ..

Comment: For floats (as asked in the question which I found with google by typing "c++ string to float"), one should use std::stof.

Comment: There are a lot of more of them. All listed in the links I provided.

Comment: Just a note that this can throw exceptions:
std::invalid_argument (if conversion failed)
std::out_of_range (if out of the range)

Comment: Buyer beware, depends on the current locale.

Answer (score 31):

Lexical cast is very nice.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using boost::lexical_cast;

int main() {
    string str = "0.6";
    double dub = lexical_cast<double>(str);
    cout << dub << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.. But it's a question for me: why my code isn't working.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: Based on ADL, he might as well have, the using defintions plus what he is actually using will probably bring into scope a vast number of std elements. Furthermore lexical_cast is insanely slow, so no +1 from me.

Comment: A nice feature of boost::lexical_cast is the error handling. If a conversion fails, an exception is thrown: `try { ... boost::lexical_cast ... } catch (std::exception const& err) { //handle excpetion }`

Comment: To be more precise, use `catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast const& err )` to catch the exception.

Answer (score 14):

You can use std::stringstream:

```
   #include <sstream>
   #include <string>
   template<typename T>
   T StringToNumber(const std::string& numberAsString)
   {
      T valor;

      std::stringstream stream(numberAsString);
      stream >> valor;
      if (stream.fail()) {
         std::runtime_error e(numberAsString);
         throw e;
      }
      return valor;
   }
```

Usage:

```
double number= StringToNumber<double>("0.6");
```

Comment: Uhm, so you think boost::lexical_cast has a terrible interface, don't you? Look at stefanB's answer! Boost does the same.

Comment: @kirsche40 Seems like a good alternative for people that don't already have dependencies with Boost (linking with Boost only to convert a std::string to numbers is a bit overkill !)

Comment: @JEan-Phillippe Jodiun
I answered to a now deleted comment, where someone recommended Boost. I am aware that Boost is most of the time overkill. By the way, for some time now usage of Boost is restricted to "newer" compilers. Older projects cannot use Boost. For example ASIO depends heavy on C++11-features like std::addressof which makes it completely worthless for C++98/C++03 compilers. IMHO, when the project started it was the intention of Boost to provide new "standardized" features for older compiler versions... :-(

Answer (score 11):

Yes, with a lexical cast. Use a stringstream and the << operator, or use Boost, they've already implemented it.

Your own version could look like:

```
template<typename to, typename from>to lexical_cast(from const &x) {
  std::stringstream os;
  to ret;

  os << x;
  os >> ret;

  return ret;  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to drag in all of boost, go with `strtod(3)` from `<cstdlib>` - it already returns a double.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
    std::string  num = "0.6";
    double temp = ::strtod(num.c_str(), 0);

    cout << num << " " << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ g++ -o s s.cc
$ ./s
0.6 0.6
$
```

Why atof() doesn't work ... what platform/compiler are you on?

Comment: Using a stringstream wouldn't require boost

Comment: Your method returns zero too. Linux.

Answer (score 7):

You can use boost lexical cast:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

string v("0.6");
double dd = boost::lexical_cast<double>(v);
cout << dd << endl;
```

Note: boost::lexical_cast throws exception so you should be prepared to deal with it when you pass invalid value, try passing string("xxx")

Answer (score 4):

With C++17, you can use [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars), which is a lighter weight faster alternative to `std::stof` and `std::stod`. It doesn't involve any memory allocation or look at the locale, and it is non-throwing.

The `std::from_chars` function returns a value of type `from_chars_result`, which is basically a struct with two fields:

```
struct from_chars_result {
    const char* ptr;
    std::errc ec;
};
```

By inspecting `ec` we can tell if the conversion was successful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>

int main()
{
    const std::string str { "12345678901234.123456" };
    double value = 0.0;
    auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value);
    if (ec != std::errc()) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't convert value";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**NB**: you need a fairly up-to-date compiler (e.g. gcc11) for `std::from_chars` to work with floating point types.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Linux

```
double s2f(string str)
{
 istringstream buffer(str);
 double temp;
 buffer >> temp;
 return temp;
}
```

it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
   double myAtof ( string &num){
      double tmp;
      sscanf ( num.c_str(), "%lf" , &tmp);
      return tmp;
   }
```

Comment: Invalid answer, how do you know the value stored in num is actually a valid floating point number? you don't check the return type of sscanf, seems like an MS coding style.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ 11 way is to use std::stod and std::to_string. Both work in Visual Studio 11.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is backing up litb in your comments. I have profound suspicions you are just not displaying the result properly.

I had the exact same thing happen to me once. I spent a whole day trying to figure out why I was getting a bad value into a 64-bit int, only to discover that printf was ignoring the second byte. You can't just pass a 64-bit value into printf like its an int.

Comment: I'm not using printf to see results... And i use that value to set window opacity, and my window is full trasparent, so value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

As to why `atof()` isn't working in the original question: the fact that it's cast to double makes me suspicious. The code shouldn't compile without `#include <stdlib.h>`, but if the cast was added to solve a compile warning, then `atof()` is not correctly declared. If the compiler assumes `atof()` returns an int, casting it will solve the conversion warning, but it will *not* cause the return value to be recognized as a double.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

... 
  std::string num = "0.6";
  double temp = atof(num.c_str());
```

should work without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dragging Boost into the equation, you could keep your string (temporarily) as a `char[]` and use `sprintf()`.

But of course if you're using Boost anyway, it's really not too much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want Boost lexical_cast for string <-> floating point anyway. That subset of use cases is the only set for which boost consistently is worse than the older functions- and they basically concentrated all their failure there, because their own performance results show a 20-25X SLOWER performance than using sscanf and printf for such conversions.

Google it yourself. boost::lexical_cast can handle something like 50 conversions and if you exclude the ones involving floating point #s its as good or better as the obvious alternatives (with the added advantage of being having a single API for all those operations). But bring in floats and its like the Titanic hitting an iceberg in terms of performance.

The old, dedicated str->double functions can all do 10000 parses in something like 30 ms (or better). lexical_cast takes something like 650 ms to do the same job.

Comment: No source? I googled it myself: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

My Problem:

1. Locale independent string to double (decimal separator always '.')
2. Error detection if string conversion fails

My solution (uses the Windows function _wcstod_l):

```
// string to convert. Note: decimal seperator is ',' here
std::wstring str = L"1,101";

// Use this for error detection
wchar_t* stopString;

// Create a locale for "C". Thus a '.' is expected as decimal separator
double dbl = _wcstod_l(str.c_str(), &stopString, _create_locale(LC_ALL, "C")); 

if (wcslen(stopString) != 0)
{
    // ... error handling ... we'll run into this because of the separator
}
```

HTH ... took me pretty long to get to this solution. And I still have the feeling that I don't know enough about string localization and stuff...