# converting String to double in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, types

Can anyone help me with a way of converting String to double in vc++?

I can't use `atoi`, since it converts char to double. But I am using `istringstream`.

```
std::istringstream stm; 

double d;
String name = "32.67";

stm.str(name);
stm >>d;
```

It will give a compilation error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::basic_istringstream::str(const std::basic_string &)' :
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const std::basic_string &'
```

Please help with different solution or correct this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::string to float or double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double)

Comment: please search the site - this question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::stringstream str() accepts a std::string as an argument.  You're passing it a System::String, wherever that comes from.  Given the funky ^ symbol you must be using C++/CLI, using .NET strings.

Use std::string unless you are for some reason required to use the .NET library, in which case you need to either use .NET conversion functions, or convert to a std::string (or char* c-string and use the << operator).

Answer (score 1):

As the other responder has suggestion, you are probably using C++/CLI.  In that case:

```
 String ^ name = "32.67";
 double d;
 d = Double::Parse(name);
```

Note that if the string cannot be parsed into a double, an exception will be thrown.  Use `Double::TryParse` if you want to avoid that (it returns false if the string cannot be parsed).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very simple in vc++/CLR programming.

```
String ^name = "32.56";
String ^no = "56";

Double number_double = Convert::ToDouble(name); // convert String to double
Int number_int = Convert::ToInt32(no); // convert String to integer
```