# C++ basics - If statement testing

Tags: c++, nan

it's my first day messing around with C++. I'm trying to do just a really basic code looking for the roots in a quadratic equation. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main () {

    int a, b, c;
    double root1, root2;

    std::cout << "Enter the integers a, b, and c to fit in the quadratic equation: ax^2 + bx + c >> " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a = ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "b = ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "c = ";
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Quadratic equation to solve is : " << a << "x^2 + " << b << "x + " << c <<std::endl;

    root1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a); 
    root2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a);

    if (root1 && root2 != nan) {
        std::cout << "root 1 = " << root1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "root 2 = " << root2 << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    std::cout << "no root exists" << std::endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double (*)(const char *)')
```

in the line:

```
if (root1 && root2 != nan)
```

I'm looking for a simple test to see if the roots exist and this obviously doesn't work. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what is `nan`? where did you declare it??

Comment: Did you mean `!isnan(root2)` ?

Comment: You need to split comparison operator. if (root1 != nan && root2 != nan).

Comment: `std::nan` is a function, not a value! See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan and use `isnan` instead.

Comment: @tgmath if you've got an answer, write it as an answer rather than a comment so that it can be upvoted and accepted as appropriate.

Comment: `int a, b, c;` Just a tip which is unrelated to the question: always initialize your variables.

Comment: You should only calculate the `sqrt` expression once and store into a variable.  This reduces the checks for errors to one statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if something is a real number, use `isnan`:

```
if(!isnan(root1) && !isnan(root2))
```

**Explanation:**

`isnan` determines if the given floating point number arg is not-a-number (NaN). It returns `true` if arg is NaN, `false` otherwise.

The NaN values are used to identify undefined or non-representable values for floating-point elements, such as the square root of negative numbers or the result of 0/0. In C++, it is implemented with function overloads for each floating-point type, each returning a bool value.

Comment: [nan is a function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/). Can't do something like `root1 != nan`.

Comment: @JohnBupit: No problem, mate!! BTW, at first time, I believed `nan` is a variable he uses. Since there is no `nan` variable declared, I understand that OP is after `nan` function. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: When you are including `<cmath>` (like you should), you should call `std::isnan`.

Comment: Yes I was planning to accept it but had to wait a few more minutes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use ([C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)):

```
#include <cmath>
...
if (!isnan(root1) && !isnan(root2))
```

Answer (score 3):

`double (*)(const char *)` is a type which represents a pointer to a function that returns a `double` and takes a `const char *` argument. You'll find if you look at a reference for `cmath` that `nan` is the function in question.

Looks like you should be able to call it with an empty string to get a suitable value:

```
nan("")
```

However, you can't provide a `double` on one side of `&&` and a `bool` on the other, so you'll need to have a suitable test for `root1` as well.

And yes, that type syntax for `nan` is a bit crazy, that's how C does function pointer syntax, and the name of a function by itself represents a pointer to it, so that's what you get out of the compiler because C++ inherited C-style function pointers.

Comment: Got it! Just went with the simple solution of checking if the value in the square root was greater than 0. Out of curiosity though, is there any simple statement to check if something is a real number?

Comment: The `double` datatype represents a real number. If you're looking for a function that checks if a `string` is a real number or not, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double). Also, please please do not _answer_ to ask a question.

Comment: `isnan()` comes from `is not a number`, so I think that using it is very good to see if it is a number or not

Answer (score 1):

Use   `if (root1 != nan("") && root2 != nan(""))`

The problem is in two places:

1. `root1` is always true except when it is `0`
2. `nan` is not declared, it should be `nan("")`

But I think it is better to use `!isnan(root1)` instead of just `nan`