# Compare two strings containing float values

Tags: c++

I am given two strings which contain a floating point number. I need to compare them. Can I directly compare the strings using `std::string::compare` and will this always give correct results? My current approach is to convert the string to float using `std::stof`, however I would prefer to avoid C++11 library functions.

Comment: @NaCl What about leading zeros? What about negative and positive zero? What about scientific notation vs fixed notation?

Comment: `stof` was not declared in this scope because you have not declared that you are using namespace `std`. So either declare `using namespace std;` at the beginning of the file, or use `std::stof` instead.

Comment: DBSystem.cpp:847:50: error: ‘stof’ is not a member of ‘std’
           `if(!condflag) flag = flag | (rec[x] >= std::stof(breakCond[k][2]));`

Comment: This sounds like an X and Y problem. Your issue is either you're not compiling in C++11 mode, or your compiler doesn't support it (i.e., MinGW bug.) Please clarify your question so that it *doesn't* rely on `std::stof`.

Comment: @remyabel It compiled in C++11 mode. However I would like to avoid c++11 mode since I do not have control over compiling environment. Are there functions similar to `stof` which do not require c++11 flag?

Comment: @Ayush Here is one way using [`std::atof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double). It also mentions `boost::lexical_cast` and `std::stringstream`. All valid C++03 options. Still, I'm convinced your question is asking too many things at once. What is your core issue? Comparing floating point numbers or converting strings to floats (which is a duplicate)?

Comment: It depends. Would you consider the strings "equal" if they contain an unequal number of [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)? Are they equal if neither one contains a number? Are you certain that the strings contain numbers which can be accurately represented as floats?

Comment: @remyabel My core issue was to compare two floating numbers given to me in string format. I was trying to avoid the conversion of string to float. But as pointed here, it would give wrong result comparing strings directly. `atof` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply comparing strings won't help you in cases like

```
a = "0.43"
b = "0.4300"
```

if you need to compare first parse them into float and then compare them

```
std::string  s1  = "0.6"
std::wstring s2 = "0.7"
float d1  = std::stof(s1);
float d2 = std::stof(s2);
```

and then compare them

here is a full program

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stof

int main ()
{
  std::string  s1  = "0.6"
  std::wstring s2 = "0.7"
  float d1  = std::stof(s1);
  float d2 = std::stof(s2);

  if(d1 == d2)
     std::cout << "Equals!";
  else
     std::cout << "Not Equals!";
  return 0;
}
```

[click here for more reading on stof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/)

Comment: @Columbo gimmi a minute

Comment: Floating point numbers shouldn't be compared for equality using `==` as they are inherently imprecise. You should e.g. instead check that the difference between the numbers is within some small bound.

Comment: `12.3` vs `4.5` is a better example :P

Answer (score 0):

What about writing some ugly codes? It may not be good practice but ...

```
int compare (const string &str1, const string &str2) {
    string *s1 = &str1, *s2 = &str2;
    int isReverse = 1;
    int len1, len2;

    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {
        s1 = &str2;
        s2 = &str1;
        isReverse = -1;
    }

    len1 = s1->length();
    len2 = s2->length();

    if (!len1) {
        if (!len2))
            return 0;
        else if ((*s2)[0] != '-')
            return 1*isReverse;
        return -1*isReverse;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while(i < len1) {
        if ((*s1)[i] > (*s2)[i])
            return 1*isReverse;
        else if ((*s1)[i] < (*s2)[i])
            return -1*isReverse;
        i++;
    }

    while (i < len2) {
        if ((*s2)[i] != '0')
            return -1*isReverse;

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Holy buckets what are you doing?!