# Convert char to vector<float>

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a problem for using my char array in C++ from using custom train HOG.This char is a like data `vector<float>` from custom HOG `https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial`. I want to detect my custom HOG Animal. So this is one sample data for +1 (Positive Image) from 49 data.

```
+1 1:0.0516209 2:0.0526671 3:0.0621273 4:0.162602 5:0.252267 6:0.220246 7:0.116933 8:0.0665012 9:0.040535 10:0.0810178 11:0.0799648 12:0.0989393 13:0.204468 14:0.252267 15:0.232619 16:0.10104 17:0.0503855 18:0.0872255 19:0.109535 20:0.135352 21:0.252267 22:0.252267 23:0.252267 24:0.19159 25:0.139957 26:0.0849861 27:0.0621954 28:0.180085 29:0.220934 30:0.252267 31:0.252267 32:0.252267 33:0.14686 34:0.133376 35:0.0798698 36:0.143804 37:0.154667 38:0.175837 39:0.175819 40:0.185156 41:0.242682 42:0.143323 43:0.0656771 44:0.0752698 45:0.120002 46:0.125042 47:0.137929 48:0.141668 49:0.238362 50:0.242682 51:0.187268 52:0.0587663 53:0.0820198 54:0.0561508 55:0.173739 56:0.235661 57:0.176866 58:0.242682 59:0.242682 60:0.120697 61:0.0926801 62:0.074838 63:0.120294 64:0.099418 65:0.165938 66:0.223667 67:0.242682 68:0.242682 69:0.242682 70:0.0941423 71:0.0576666 72:0.0232888 73:0.030905 74:0.0741619 75:0.128762 76:0.241179 77:0.284917 78:0.284917 79:0.0878371 80:0.057604 81:0.0254226 82:0.0749189 83:0.0660299 84:0.112901 85:0.165158 86:0.284917 87:0.205528 88:0.0918434 89:0.0600073 90:0.0772874 91:0.0374085 92:0.119716 93:0.183876 94:0.237916 95:0.284917 96:0.284917 97:0.11597 98:0.0431861 99:0.0226412 100:0.053028 101:0.0779262 102:0.138294 103:0.197107 104:0.284917 105:0.284917 106:0.155058 107:0.09058 108:0.0685508 109:0.107512 110:0.0580869 111:0.155158 112:0.243893 113:0.215341 114:0.129598 115:0.048822 116:0.0425757 117:0.0809534 118:0.1627 119:0.124774 120:0.198517 121:0.259591 122:0.259591 123:0.109071 124:0.0437223 125:0.0560505 126:0.0753148 127:0.0582958 128:0.0646337 129:0.207277 130:0.259591 131:0.248938 132:0.259591 133:0.135874 134:0.113958 135:0.061379 136:0.0877517 137:0.115159 138:0.223133 139:0.259591 140:0.259591 141:0.259591 142:0.135361 143:0.0905518 144:0.0649403 145:0.104641 146:0.139505 147:0.234039 148:0.234039 149:0.209601 150:0.213197 151:0.132382 152:0.0932568 153:0.0901358 154:0.185335 155:0.232361 156:0.234039 157:0.234039 158:0.154098 159:0.167337 160:0.179891 161:0.118966 162:0.131475 163:0.0564679 164:0.105363 165:0.167412 166:0.231988 167:0.228415 168:0.228708 169:0.104494 170:0.072458 171:0.0586462 172:0.0992585 173:0.117884 174:0.104316 175:0.151379 176:0.187837 177:0.156796 178:0.232444 179:0.139886 180:0.0964207 181:0.145255 182:0.198792 183:0.150749 184:0.221525 185:0.19881 186:0.178096 187:0.226074 188:0.121964 189:0.102861 190:0.0437534 191:0.131493 192:0.178541 193:0.21926 194:0.234759 195:0.254669 196:0.157603 197:0.0723847 198:0.0244493 199:0.065348 200:0.0853451 201:0.0624319 202:0.103251 203:0.139865 204:0.220055 205:0.254669 206:0.223438 207:0.0848672 208:0.0425032 209:0.0791857 210:0.138352 211:0.157657 212:0.200656 213:0.254669 214:0.254669 215:0.167132 216:0.0369475 217:0.0398139 218:0.124495 219:0.180236 220:0.185851 221:0.262945 222:0.262945 223:0.142996 224:0.09139 225:0.0423195 226:0.0673232 227:0.067754 228:0.118807 229:0.177049 230:0.217177 231:0.262945 232:0.206083 233:0.154343 234:0.129637 235:0.071941 236:0.0843471 237:0.154425 238:0.167051 239:0.223171 240:0.262945 241:0.230233 242:0.168113 243:0.0707214 244:0.0988057 245:0.110709 246:0.10464 247:0.170808 248:0.142613 249:0.198069 250:0.193661 251:0.206063 252:0.139514 253:0.070888 254:0.0546235 255:0.0987665 256:0.179403 257:0.176451 258:0.231507 259:0.170609 260:0.170777 261:0.134404 262:0.0957243 263:0.0741578 264:0.113292 265:0.210238 266:0.215958 267:0.264889 268:0.175568 269:0.120427 270:0.0934888 271:0.107025 272:0.127747 273:0.0658595 274:0.172265 275:0.187371 276:0.264889 277:0.179685 278:0.217699 279:0.124863 280:0.140482 281:0.0842961 282:0.0816219 283:0.186152 284:0.26147 285:0.264889 286:0.14057 287:0.18035 288:0.149876 289:0.0789043 290:0.170528 291:0.259454 292:0.244211 293:0.259454 294:0.255461 295:0.124829 296:0.0738446 297:0.0424127 298:0.197806 299:0.162143 300:0.144715 301:0.122082 302:0.171563 303:0.123079 304:0.188536 305:0.128817 306:0.0890725 307:0.0940822 308:0.185499 309:0.259454 310:0.252905 311:0.211187 312:0.161549 313:0.115569 314:0.0730725 315:0.0770362 316:0.226353 317:0.181456 318:0.223296 319:0.170029 320:0.117185 321:0.0981806 322:0.0746445 323:0.060523 324:0.0916957 325:0.0950073 326:0.0789168 327:0.0433256 328:0.0477858 329:0.109855 330:0.13269 331:0.207804 332:0.182029 333:0.0941013 334:0.118187 335:0.0871392 336:0.0667544 337:0.125589 338:0.256858 339:0.254672 340:0.256858 341:0.219227 342:0.102974 343:0.160436 344:0.140071 345:0.0956094 346:0.0954186 347:0.105212 348:0.0769432 349:0.134467 350:0.104214 351:0.153261 352:0.236158 353:0.218971 354:0.134611 355:0.232192 356:0.256858 357:0.160758 358:0.229581 359:0.215932 360:0.256858 361:0.131302 362:0.0838311 363:0.0680505 364:0.0964724 365:0.167542 366:0.163733 367:0.159702 368:0.11763 369:0.0803405 370:0.147074 371:0.153463 372:0.141674 373:0.108444 374:0.110367 375:0.155245 376:0.0968434 377:0.0853039 378:0.0769986 379:0.233289 380:0.184741 381:0.148944 382:0.195778 383:0.249193 384:0.148996 385:0.183793 386:0.157546 387:0.249193 388:0.249193 389:0.249193 390:0.249193 391:0.16308 392:0.180707 393:0.154442 394:0.126717 395:0.145393 396:0.249193 397:0.0897672 398:0.14826 399:0.16095 400:0.191101 401:0.183119 402:0.242813 403:0.0559302 404:0.0604032 405:0.0441353 406:0.0892086 407:0.0911337 408:0.0933983 409:0.204716 410:0.249644 411:0.24499 412:0.0836525 413:0.0743139 414:0.0867809 415:0.230095 416:0.209791 417:0.249644 418:0.249644 419:0.203505 420:0.169885 421:0.0601984 422:0.0619023 423:0.149432 424:0.095661 425:0.119704 426:0.185102 427:0.249644 428:0.249644 429:0.2331 430:0.172669 431:0.0571165 432:0.0554624 433:0.105544 434:0.124474 435:0.204209 436:0.149226 437:0.287671 438:0.233312 439:0.158538 440:0.085772 441:0.102165 442:0.117022 443:0.122671 444:0.160237 445:0.151971 446:0.143499 447:0.129942 448:0.0959389 449:0.0556028 450:0.0864025 451:0.167466 452:0.0568043 453:0.105169 454:0.28099 455:0.287671 456:0.287671 457:0.203573 458:0.0838686 459:0.125802 460:0.19001 461:0.0978778 462:0.118772 463:0.103927 464:0.206477 465:0.221949 466:0.147634 467:0.109453 468:0.21046 469:0.0934628 470:0.111775 471:0.0854255 472:0.0896416 473:0.0980298 474:0.0729928 475:0.101601 476:0.0468797 477:0.0791986 478:0.158492 479:0.162197 480:0.188256 481:0.310893 482:0.298819 483:0.152905 484:0.154461 485:0.104955 486:0.219529 487:0.105981 488:0.109796 489:0.0943929 490:0.116314 491:0.211338 492:0.183864 493:0.15099 494:0.0466525 495:0.0814759 496:0.0826441 497:0.133331 498:0.189644 499:0.310893 500:0.310893 501:0.310893 502:0.178649 503:0.0622459 504:0.0721505 505:0.161893 506:0.112677 507:0.17197 508:0.261516 509:0.231606 510:0.12838 511:0.119647 512:0.0897209 513:0.204429 514:0.258437 515:0.151017 516:0.232684 517:0.106046 518:0.119519 519:0.118933 520:0.102533 521:0.109681 522:0.261516 523:0.0781687 524:0.0865439 525:0.120502 526:0.261516 527:0.261516 528:0.261516 529:0.0982907 530:0.0651658 531:0.0631546 532:0.205084 533:0.151398 534:0.215174 535:0.0894046 536:0.133384 537:0.157612 538:0.100458 539:0.0809739 540:0.148817 541:0.239039 542:0.163965 543:0.24837 544:0.147138 545:0.137003 546:0.198188 547:0.0955781 548:0.0704638 549:0.201737 550:0.09251 551:0.13307 552:0.203236 553:0.230284 554:0.24581 555:0.24837 556:0.163676 557:0.0441309 558:0.05486 559:0.200242 560:0.18874 561:0.24837 562:0.122286 563:0.111089 564:0.170059 565:0.0974838 566:0.0557162 567:0.139893 568:0.142029 569:0.135066 570:0.239535 571:0.165015 572:0.151529 573:0.215339 574:0.109499 575:0.0477798 576:0.102104 577:0.142869 578:0.0506508 579:0.099281 580:0.311296 581:0.311296 582:0.29235 583:0.0853785 584:0.0298867 585:0.0839334 586:0.217339 587:0.102943 588:0.0936696 589:0.0937782 590:0.148731 591:0.120643 592:0.0644866 593:0.105494 594:0.223154 595:0.124304 596:0.0630043 597:0.0882641 598:0.290856 599:0.311296 600:0.311296 601:0.159524 602:0.0136488 603:0.0657668 604:0.204307 605:0.149414 606:0.111302 607:0.106827 608:0.11079 609:0.117657 610:0.0400945 611:0.0877738 612:0.183063 613:0.133036 614:0.11257 615:0.114527 616:0.079359 617:0.144871 618:0.166868 619:0.0980467 620:0.0701586 621:0.136393 622:0.144127 623:0.204131 624:0.184349 625:0.273352 626:0.273352 627:0.273352 628:0.117483 629:0.0403787 630:0.101049 631:0.154879 632:0.180959 633:0.167622 634:0.138856 635:0.0361039 636:0.0806388 637:0.0373684 638:0.0916881 639:0.156742 640:0.223871 641:0.273352 642:0.271826 643:0.273352 644:0.165789 645:0.124406 646:0.0731598 647:0.143914 648:0.174675 649:0.112238 650:0.164751 651:0.0874189 652:0.161027 653:0.280177 654:0.223749 655:0.0456342 656:0.0362706 657:0.0407592 658:0.236262 659:0.280177 660:0.280177 661:0.0951557 662:0.137062 663:0.0833213 664:0.0380415 665:0.0730444 666:0.0742162 667:0.173875 668:0.280177 669:0.210483 670:0.195704 671:0.156123 672:0.0756225 673:0.0553245 674:0.106288 675:0.11255 676:0.231428 677:0.280177 678:0.280177 679:0.132035 680:0.0793173 681:0.0650503 682:0.0857836 683:0.126709 684:0.141397 685:0.215868 686:0.298669 687:0.298669 688:0.208136 689:0.0907796 690:0.0632681 691:0.0523893 692:0.0769242 693:0.0955798 694:0.0874953 695:0.098873 696:0.244548 697:0.186292 698:0.111636 699:0.105521 700:0.0849176 701:0.0982519 702:0.0771137 703:0.180454 704:0.298669 705:0.298669 706:0.255643 707:0.0955855 708:0.0588408 709:0.0775926 710:0.161626 711:0.132766 712:0.078477 713:0.0844616 714:0.298669 715:0.242583 716:0.107347 717:0.0798445 718:0.0853468 719:0.103689 720:0.065806 721:0.0357221 722:0.0298848 723:0.0814559 724:0.167687 725:0.266033 726:0.266033 727:0.250278 728:0.0899015 729:0.0693378 730:0.074513 731:0.0717591 732:0.120642 733:0.0856944 734:0.0741726 735:0.111318 736:0.0733351 737:0.111474 738:0.102383 739:0.0333341 740:0.0476535 741:0.090083 742:0.119321 743:0.266033 744:0.266033 745:0.266033 746:0.266033 747:0.186286 748:0.126744 749:0.0692135 750:0.161342 751:0.110722 752:0.266033 753:0.180974 754:0.180172 755:0.266033 756:0.23479 757:0.117383 758:0.159488 759:0.246485 760:0.240844 761:0.0489906 762:0.0327636 763:0.0302243 764:0.0614286 765:0.0963371 766:0.174301 767:0.246485 768:0.246485 769:0.246485 770:0.0998213 771:0.0707082 772:0.0477948 773:0.138016 774:0.121114 775:0.204169 776:0.113 777:0.246485 778:0.220392 779:0.246485 780:0.113499 781:0.046402 782:0.0894608 783:0.168363 784:0.192057 785:0.17405 786:0.246485 787:0.221395 788:0.227333 789:0.139138 790:0.0606163 791:0.0669251 792:0.162615 793:0.168169 794:0.264854 795:0.243766 796:0.140564 797:0.0976328 798:0.0677347 799:0.0445176 800:0.15511 801:0.15869 802:0.264854 803:0.264854 804:0.246155 805:0.104299 806:0.0436364 807:0.0780234 808:0.131923 809:0.166165 810:0.2136 811:0.132863 812:0.238265 813:0.157387 814:0.103066 815:0.151245 816:0.096932 817:0.0574446 818:0.107677 819:0.132774 820:0.238755 821:0.264854 822:0.112574 823:0.141528 824:0.182357 825:0.106048 826:0.12458 827:0.150181 828:0.164209 829:0.24785 830:0.24785 831:0.24785 832:0.191579 833:0.0602815 834:0.0766117 835:0.118639 836:0.180041 837:0.177137 838:0.0915748 839:0.10766 840:0.24785 841:0.199659 842:0.0899677 843:0.130194 844:0.105077 845:0.0814451 846:0.0724681 847:0.220688 848:0.24785 849:0.145892 850:0.207808 851:0.151263 852:0.0936182 853:0.13452 854:0.151408 855:0.202105 856:0.107693 857:0.143771 858:0.233332 859:0.201684 860:0.184008 861:0.147185 862:0.120236 863:0.101269 864:0.155512
```

This is a one sample data char for -1 (Negative Image) from 22 data

```
-1 1:0.165189 2:0.164981 3:0.116941 4:0.11345 5:0.128291 6:0.118881 7:0.118121 8:0.119914 9:0.146362 10:0.22207 11:0.168804 12:0.131921 13:0.0325443 14:0.119404 15:0.0934581 16:0.140226 17:0.14196 18:0.189821 19:0.158814 20:0.22207 21:0.22207 22:0.22207 23:0.171607 24:0.22207 25:0.129215 26:0.111086 27:0.10872 28:0.215906 29:0.22207 30:0.22207 31:0.115586 32:0.217826 33:0.201578 34:0.185748 35:0.221459 36:0.13509 37:0.244393 38:0.144381 39:0.091317 40:0.104887 41:0.109409 42:0.0808339 43:0.201065 44:0.151304 45:0.244393 46:0.174446 47:0.0567968 48:0.080337 49:0.213625 50:0.213693 51:0.164544 52:0.111507 53:0.0796814 54:0.204111 55:0.244393 56:0.20372 57:0.191114 58:0.1397 59:0.18421 60:0.101435 61:0.199973 62:0.222469 63:0.216875 64:0.211165 65:0.0773931 66:0.118949 67:0.191791 68:0.200784 69:0.131772 70:0.0793873 71:0.0912936 72:0.159131 73:0.0322933 74:0.0280694 75:0.0832985 76:0.279318 77:0.279318 78:0.269168 79:0.0456666 80:0.0349583 81:0.0369597 82:0.0410106 83:0.0427188 84:0.0750417 85:0.25879 86:0.279318 87:0.244269 88:0.0772164 89:0.0476613 90:0.0417625 91:0.0720284 92:0.0398592 93:0.12366 94:0.279318 95:0.279318 96:0.268971 97:0.0573086 98:0.0637903 99:0.0585917 100:0.0461432 101:0.0577249 102:0.0884513 103:0.279318 104:0.279318 105:0.279318 106:0.126438 107:0.0759421 108:0.0341966 109:0.0250005 110:0.0316974 111:0.139563 112:0.166949 113:0.29421 114:0.221636 115:0.0810138 116:0.0342555 117:0.0313547 118:0.0479524 119:0.0514007 120:0.180336 121:0.267341 122:0.29421 123:0.243187 124:0.0989395 125:0.0174275 126:0.0360526 127:0.04031 128:0.0520151 129:0.0980714 130:0.211785 131:0.29421 132:0.275555 133:0.104354 134:0.0625526 135:0.0342207 136:0.0551942 137:0.0692367 138:0.136018 139:0.29421 140:0.29421 141:0.291599 142:0.0896768 143:0.0701223 144:0.054212 145:0.0846012 146:0.127436 147:0.154971 148:0.185678 149:0.138068 150:0.220294 151:0.154764 152:0.216335 153:0.127472 154:0.0821902 155:0.152511 156:0.145114 157:0.148917 158:0.212201 159:0.205325 160:0.186903 161:0.220836 162:0.14874 163:0.0932718 164:0.12849 165:0.162032 166:0.15564 167:0.120401 168:0.0633266 169:0.167134 170:0.178766 171:0.173912 172:0.143696 173:0.194207 174:0.183787 175:0.220836 176:0.180148 177:0.136166 178:0.208015 179:0.163623 180:0.220836 181:0.120408 182:0.129811 183:0.142702 184:0.167791 185:0.231033 186:0.194716 187:0.160527 188:0.193976 189:0.153228 190:0.10336 191:0.0783104 192:0.098132 193:0.153817 194:0.176692 195:0.193027 196:0.0924424 197:0.120699 198:0.0935112 199:0.112967 200:0.147123 201:0.164189 202:0.231033 203:0.231033 204:0.231033 205:0.231033 206:0.162097 207:0.224809 208:0.0760801 209:0.071225 210:0.119989 211:0.207672 212:0.231033 213:0.231033 214:0.166871 215:0.169937 216:0.0753017 217:0.0842727 218:0.0666493 219:0.161964 220:0.266701 221:0.266701 222:0.176588 223:0.0702919 224:0.0818697 225:0.0655066 226:0.0753267 227:0.0675327 228:0.119599 229:0.266701 230:0.266701 231:0.266701 232:0.101036 233:0.0676756 234:0.0477131 235:0.119669 236:0.0638264 237:0.138472 238:0.266701 239:0.266701 240:0.198251 241:0.110793 242:0.124044 243:0.082423 244:0.119888 245:0.0467489 246:0.0846935 247:0.240643 248:0.266701 249:0.266701 250:0.154854 251:0.0828445 252:0.0828198 253:0.0556783 254:0.0834026 255:0.0960806 256:0.233444 257:0.256824 258:0.231747 259:0.097193 260:0.0586042 261:0.0469406 262:0.048689 263:0.0551516 264:0.176766 265:0.256824 266:0.256824 267:0.256824 268:0.113768 269:0.101768 270:0.0666612 271:0.0960386 272:0.0578602 273:0.0820714 274:0.230679 275:0.256824 276:0.25561 277:0.12441 278:0.0438538 279:0.0869941 280:0.0691182 281:0.0685209 282:0.240246 283:0.256824 284:0.256824 285:0.256824 286:0.155867 287:0.0565592 288:0.072656 289:0.128703 290:0.167957 291:0.144379 292:0.11902 293:0.0606325 294:0.0658879 295:0.141887 296:0.112322 297:0.179095 298:0.202466 299:0.226054 300:0.219005 301:0.226054 302:0.122938 303:0.0827926 304:0.141151 305:0.126922 306:0.226054 307:0.153439 308:0.121057 309:0.0939595 310:0.0804262 311:0.0773079 312:0.225928 313:0.226054 314:0.226054 315:0.164541 316:0.195012 317:0.14765 318:0.22116 319:0.226054 320:0.149704 321:0.147114 322:0.186823 323:0.180149 324:0.183888 325:0.128835 326:0.186127 327:0.196009 328:0.244364 329:0.199039 330:0.172299 331:0.176115 332:0.110407 333:0.186652 334:0.0365583 335:0.0633698 336:0.125213 337:0.244364 338:0.244364 339:0.158732 340:0.137017 341:0.102119 342:0.0342484 343:0.112357 344:0.17319 345:0.193854 346:0.244364 347:0.230252 348:0.160939 349:0.183943 350:0.113913 351:0.116754 352:0.0479493 353:0.116472 354:0.127399 355:0.244364 356:0.244364 357:0.215994 358:0.138377 359:0.0672013 360:0.0607577 361:0.0501909 362:0.0401571 363:0.0640584 364:0.252343 365:0.299526 366:0.178897 367:0.111362 368:0.10159 369:0.0542481 370:0.0564211 371:0.0407244 372:0.0270717 373:0.149451 374:0.299526 375:0.224833 376:0.155869 377:0.107137 378:0.0522519 379:0.0191248 380:0.0490183 381:0.0686875 382:0.258836 383:0.299526 384:0.299526 385:0.187584 386:0.0866667 387:0.0351289 388:0.0286399 389:0.0463949 390:0.032434 391:0.143816 392:0.299526 393:0.299526 394:0.232712 395:0.11592 396:0.0380866 397:0.0667227 398:0.037487 399:0.0759884 400:0.166003 401:0.265254 402:0.224348 403:0.168128 404:0.100326 405:0.0758107 406:0.0665216 407:0.0765357 408:0.186262 409:0.265254 410:0.265254 411:0.222812 412:0.197906 413:0.125523 414:0.0724461 415:0.0579812 416:0.0509779 417:0.0997114 418:0.104753 419:0.191219 420:0.236794 421:0.210026 422:0.122795 423:0.0943381 424:0.0599785 425:0.0548401 426:0.197092 427:0.209497 428:0.265254 429:0.240964 430:0.209019 431:0.182497 432:0.124581 433:0.176302 434:0.0776206 435:0.0506692 436:0.0399974 437:0.0812255 438:0.193272 439:0.236511 440:0.236511 441:0.120556 442:0.123942 443:0.0673944 444:0.132632 445:0.140996 446:0.203874 447:0.136805 448:0.233621 449:0.198939 450:0.102627 451:0.236511 452:0.164565 453:0.124979 454:0.107888 455:0.236511 456:0.147091 457:0.165962 458:0.169333 459:0.159593 460:0.214363 461:0.130637 462:0.157107 463:0.231993 464:0.236511 465:0.146494 466:0.221547 467:0.144449 468:0.0724779 469:0.0574487 470:0.0998127 471:0.179924 472:0.222595 473:0.233685 474:0.123515 475:0.176483 476:0.1222 477:0.085901 478:0.0483278 479:0.099564 480:0.134563 481:0.177057 482:0.177276 483:0.214734 484:0.149281 485:0.0774847 486:0.0845015 487:0.155056 488:0.145278 489:0.182742 490:0.233685 491:0.233685 492:0.206951 493:0.210404 494:0.141436 495:0.085324 496:0.125075 497:0.153648 498:0.136137 499:0.218661 500:0.233685 501:0.233685 502:0.209033 503:0.147049 504:0.149031 505:0.0214942 506:0.0398588 507:0.0530374 508:0.144124 509:0.270467 510:0.270467 511:0.235782 512:0.0778165 513:0.0537365 514:0.0411014 515:0.0248039 516:0.0278 517:0.122121 518:0.270467 519:0.270467 520:0.197063 521:0.0685708 522:0.0515143 523:0.0643562 524:0.103831 525:0.0746234 526:0.253503 527:0.270467 528:0.270467 529:0.214217 530:0.140651 531:0.106257 532:0.0697366 533:0.0627681 534:0.0819134 535:0.203325 536:0.270467 537:0.255747 538:0.174644 539:0.110363 540:0.0649582 541:0.0596835 542:0.0319175 543:0.108309 544:0.141434 545:0.166728 546:0.223207 547:0.127996 548:0.0727497 549:0.114249 550:0.0439684 551:0.0507542 552:0.260922 553:0.235674 554:0.228785 555:0.256935 556:0.202484 557:0.115345 558:0.157002 559:0.0934015 560:0.0604939 561:0.147392 562:0.192817 563:0.249423 564:0.159143 565:0.121385 566:0.0668934 567:0.100558 568:0.109496 569:0.077006 570:0.20242 571:0.260922 572:0.260922 573:0.260922 574:0.180639 575:0.127926 576:0.151687 577:0.136773 578:0.0809913 579:0.0776634 580:0.132654 581:0.248765 582:0.216725 583:0.20438 584:0.150821 585:0.129429 586:0.129919 587:0.0701566 588:0.123463 589:0.248765 590:0.248765 591:0.223227 592:0.164957 593:0.0966106 594:0.0659052 595:0.0787546 596:0.0290063 597:0.0257091 598:0.113578 599:0.166322 600:0.238476 601:0.248765 602:0.165989 603:0.159303 604:0.0631109 605:0.0595377 606:0.105214 607:0.20948 608:0.248765 609:0.248765 610:0.224377 611:0.173756 612:0.142226 613:0.143682 614:0.0938467 615:0.105686 616:0.210905 617:0.224165 618:0.190947 619:0.129758 620:0.111185 621:0.0953981 622:0.147093 623:0.149196 624:0.0861645 625:0.152032 626:0.187777 627:0.183757 628:0.171791 629:0.151648 630:0.175903 631:0.0900764 632:0.102466 633:0.169305 634:0.224165 635:0.224165 636:0.224165 637:0.162728 638:0.182722 639:0.166412 640:0.128726 641:0.140324 642:0.124896 643:0.188197 644:0.167964 645:0.147457 646:0.224165 647:0.224165 648:0.193428 649:0.0943543 650:0.176172 651:0.137621 652:0.225134 653:0.241072 654:0.241072 655:0.144834 656:0.168161 657:0.158896 658:0.0624028 659:0.10548 660:0.129502 661:0.188486 662:0.241072 663:0.186153 664:0.0718425 665:0.132397 666:0.0569417 667:0.0855979 668:0.125764 669:0.170918 670:0.189774 671:0.188451 672:0.19037 673:0.241072 674:0.20558 675:0.171655 676:0.0559339 677:0.0920969 678:0.172327 679:0.169929 680:0.241072 681:0.241072 682:0.104605 683:0.139609 684:0.0667545 685:0.11515 686:0.0890274 687:0.10076 688:0.132808 689:0.22165 690:0.138604 691:0.0990266 692:0.0876022 693:0.0736106 694:0.152001 695:0.129801 696:0.0849636 697:0.15539 698:0.264333 699:0.264333 700:0.106546 701:0.073908 702:0.119538 703:0.130928 704:0.118515 705:0.170862 706:0.16433 707:0.264333 708:0.262308 709:0.120987 710:0.154378 711:0.0877667 712:0.162938 713:0.189108 714:0.193231 715:0.264333 716:0.264333 717:0.264333 718:0.115601 719:0.0651449 720:0.125981 721:0.0825706 722:0.0673261 723:0.0593216 724:0.101584 725:0.1499 726:0.218329 727:0.196984 728:0.123027 729:0.133464 730:0.1031 731:0.159933 732:0.112227 733:0.174007 734:0.21066 735:0.22477 736:0.149839 737:0.160006 738:0.206876 739:0.141864 740:0.128486 741:0.134463 742:0.166415 743:0.226768 744:0.226768 745:0.143225 746:0.124002 747:0.133107 748:0.221277 749:0.226768 750:0.136615 751:0.226768 752:0.223652 753:0.183763 754:0.104537 755:0.107716 756:0.223979 757:0.0732851 758:0.151202 759:0.208175 760:0.232111 761:0.180488 762:0.143654 763:0.155287 764:0.132972 765:0.154042 766:0.0753628 767:0.125398 768:0.140134 769:0.228124 770:0.166471 771:0.180407 772:0.232111 773:0.173556 774:0.151088 775:0.148462 776:0.195102 777:0.129791 778:0.213696 779:0.18879 780:0.170324 781:0.136653 782:0.0846517 783:0.118099 784:0.089498 785:0.169475 786:0.150151 787:0.167966 788:0.232111 789:0.232111 790:0.232111 791:0.101047 792:0.0833457 793:0.0470676 794:0.0660972 795:0.156254 796:0.168749 797:0.197927 798:0.181583 799:0.220255 800:0.159314 801:0.155548 802:0.0514689 803:0.0698276 804:0.165299 805:0.154805 806:0.190739 807:0.217868 808:0.123575 809:0.0779835 810:0.085956 811:0.0641623 812:0.236692 813:0.225759 814:0.200059 815:0.236692 816:0.181915 817:0.226816 818:0.094419 819:0.109284 820:0.0856719 821:0.236692 822:0.220149 823:0.215216 824:0.236692 825:0.214892 826:0.0952514 827:0.0509508 828:0.109337 829:0.0759689 830:0.107933 831:0.134389 832:0.143675 833:0.18093 834:0.240035 835:0.129176 836:0.0990904 837:0.0868207 838:0.0702544 839:0.171471 840:0.159565 841:0.201894 842:0.219346 843:0.220406 844:0.113385 845:0.0840742 846:0.121089 847:0.0835598 848:0.186167 849:0.148673 850:0.255102 851:0.255102 852:0.255102 853:0.0959296 854:0.0896823 855:0.0881329 856:0.0680724 857:0.169128 858:0.169832 859:0.255102 860:0.255102 861:0.200765 862:0.128307 863:0.161612 864:0.161189
```

So I want to convert this data to `vector<float>` for `hog.setSVMdetector(const vector<float>& detector);` looping from 1:0.xxxxxxx to 864:0.xxxxxx

So, Do you have an idea for this problem ?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? To me, it sounds like just "read the first integer, then the remaining numbers as float, adding to a vector.

Comment: there are non-float characters like ":" in it, how do you want to treat them? In general use stringstreams >> float operators in c++ like at least one of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double

Comment: I don't know kind of data for `vector<float>`, so until know i'm confused to what to do for this data... @mats-petersson @micka

Comment: Without you posting what you have tried, it's hard to give good advice. There is an answer below, but it's not exactly the complete solution.

Comment: This is libsvm format to store sparse vectors, with a leading label number. You can have an example on how to parse it at [libsvm github](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp), in function `svm_load_model`. Since this is highly coupled with internal C structures, the other linked answer may be better for your purposes.

Comment: ( a reminder ) OpenCV 3.x have a sample program [train_HOG.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp)

Comment: I was triying to use OpenCV 3.x sdk for Android..but still get following error   `Error:error: 'const class CvSVM' has no member named 'getSupportVectors'` @sturkmen

Comment: Really @Miki, this is libsvm format ? can you explain to me for combine HOG with libsvm ?

Comment: You're using a support vector machine (SVM), which in opencv is based on libsvm. Nothing you should investigate deeper, actually. Note that opencv 3 has no member CvSVM, but ml::SVM. It seems you're running opencv 2.4.x code with opencv 3.x, and that won't work. Also, there should be already a method to load these data. I can't search for it now, though.

Comment: thanks @Miki, for your explanation about `Note that opencv 3 has no member CvSVM, but ml::SVM. It seems you're running opencv 2.4.x code with opencv 3.x, and that won't work` I forgot to changes my include to OpenCV 3.x directories in Android.mk

Comment: but, Do you know for adopt rectangle for OpenCV 3.x ? @Miki

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. You can probably explain it better in a new question

Comment: @Miki, I was have my own train data from using `https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial` and make features.dat, but `svm = StatModel::load<SVM>` can't use that..So, what I must do ?

Comment: `load` works with xml or yml files, saved with `save`. It seems that you saved your data using Svmlight, so it's a different file format. You can ask a new question, with a public link to your file and a description of its format.

Comment: @Miki, maybe you klik this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549826/generate-single-detecting-feature-vector-from-calculated-svm-support-vectors) 
This link is my new question with a following error from `libimagepreocessing.so` and I don't know how to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
void toVector(char * input, std::vector<float> &v)
{
    std::stringstream ssin(input + 2);
    while (ssin.good()){
        std::string token;
        ssin >> token;
        v.push_back(std::atof(token.substr(token.find_first_of(":") + 1).c_str()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What would exactly you do for ":" separate or delete it ? Do you know `vector<float>` needed for`hog.setSVMdetector(const vector<float>& detector);` ? @selçuk-cihan

Comment: I don't know what setSVMdetector actually expects, i thought you only need the part after the ":" for each entry, so i just skipped that part to get the float value part.

Comment: So, If my data in char like : `0.00618567 0.00224441 0.002006603 0.001813437 0.003761207 -0.001850192 -0.001011893 -0.00342476 0.003790586 0.002385935 0.002647488 0.004411637 0.005938921 0.00698391 0.004522655 0.001524881 -0.002673242`, How to convert it from char to vector<float> @selçuk-cihan ?