# How to convert string to double with specified number of precision in c++

Tags: c++, string, double, precision

How to convert string to double with specified number of precision in c++
code snippet as below:

```
  double value;
  CString thestring(_T("1234567890123.4"));
 value = _tcstod(thestring,NULL);

The value is coming as this:1234567890123.3999
expected value is:1234567890123.4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "number of precision"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::string to float or double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double)

Comment: std::stod then round to needed precision

Comment: What do you mean by "number of precision" when converting **to** double?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can use `strtod` or `std::stod` for the conversion and then round to your desired precision. For the actual rounding, a web search will provide lots of code examples.

But the details are more complicated than you might think: The string is (probably) a decimal representation of the number while the double is binary. I guess that you want to round to a specified number of decimal digits. The problem is that most decimal floating point decimal numbers cannot be exactly represented in binary. Even for numbers like 0.1 it is not possible.

You also need to define what kind of precision you are interested in. Is it the total number of digits (relative precision) or the number of digits after the decimal point (absolute precision).

Comment: in relation to the loss of precision, you might want to consider multiplying your numbers by 10^x to remove your decimal place and use whole numbers, then you won't have precision issues ;) (just divide by right at the end, or simply display them with a decimal point instead)

Answer (score 2):

The floating-point `double` type **can not exactly represent** the value `1234567890123.4` and `1234567890123.3999` is the best it can represent and that is what the result is. Note that floating point types (e.g. IEEE-754) can not exactly represent all real numbers, hence these use approximations for most cases.

To be more precise, according to IEEE-754 double-precision floating point format `1234567890123.4` is represented as the hexadecimal value of `4271F71FB04CB666`, where in binary the sign bit is `0`, the 11 exponent and 52 singificand bits are `10000100111` and `0001111101110001111110110000010011001011011001100110` respectively. So this results in the value of (-1)<sup>sign</sup>×2<sup>exponent</sup>×(1.significand bits) = 1×2<sup>40</sup>×1.1228329550462148311851251492043957114219 = 1234567890123.39990234375.

Note that not even a 128-bit floating point would store the value exactly. It would still result in 1234567890123.39999999999999999999991529670527456996609316774993203580379486083984375. Maybe you should instead attempt to use some fixed-point or rational number types instead.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stod` is generic and doesn't give this kind of manipulation. Thus, you have to craft something of your own, like I did below using `std::stringstream` and `<iomanip>` facilities:

```
double stodpre(std::string const &str, std::size_t const p) {
  std::stringstream sstrm;
  sstrm << std::setprecision(p) << std::fixed << str << std::endl;

  double d;
  sstrm >> d;

  return d;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61ae860a548e18fb)

Comment: Interesting - why do `std::setprecision(p)` and `std::fixed` work although you are writing a string? Up to now I thought they only affect floating point fields.

Comment: @FrankPuffer good question, I guess they've made stringstream intelligent enough to understand that insertion value is a floating point number and to apply specified precision on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the precision with which a decimal number is stored.
Decimal numbers are stored in binary using the floating point notation.

What you can do is to control the precision of what is displayed on outputting the number.

For example, do this to control the precision of the output to 2 digits -

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
std::cout << value;
```

You can give any number for the precision.